# Why do I get this error message very often?

Tags: vb.net

"There is no row at position 0." 
Hi I keep on getting this error message.

```
If mytable.Rows.Count >= 0  then
dim  myid = dt.Rows(0).Item(6).ToString
End if
```

Please help me in this matter and I would never ever like to see this message again.Thanking you all.

```
qry_Sql = qry_Sql + " select SRNO,EMPNO,ATTN_YR,ATTN_MONTH,"
    qry_Sql = qry_Sql + " GRP,TOT_HRS,MY_ID "
    qry_Sql = qry_Sql + " from ATTD_HRS  "
    qry_Sql = qry_Sql + " ORDER BY EMP_NO "

    If mytable.Rows.Count <= 0 Then
    mygrp = dt.Rows(0).Item(5).ToString ---------------------
    myid = dt.Rows(0).Item(6).ToString 
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because mytable has no row at position 0, (`rows(0)` part).
You should check if there are rows/items before using them.

Answer (score 2):

You should check to see if your table contains any rows...

```
If mytable.rows.Count > 0 then
    If mytable.rows(0).items(2) >= 0 then
        dim  myid = dt.Rows(0).Item(6).ToString
    End if
End if
```

Comment: I am doing that...sorry I dint mention this before.

Comment: From your edited post i see "If mytable.Rows.Count <= 0 Then" Thats the wrong way around, you should check if there more than 0 so use '>'

Comment: Thank you that was correct.But while debugging the pointer comes on I and then goes directly to End If.So it means there are more than 0. But I need to store the value in the variable.How can I do that?

Comment: the amount of rows? dim rowcount = mytable.rows.Count

Comment: I mean i wanted to store the value of the variable(myid,mygrp) from the table.